# How do I output Full Range RGB in Ubuntu 18.04.1?

Tags: 18.04, graphics, monitor, colors, amdgpu

I have followed [this tutorial](https://blog.tingping.se/2018/12/01/amdgpu-fullrgb.html). However, I keep getting an error while booting into the system

```
[drm:drm_load_edid_firmware [drm]] *ERROR* Requesting EDID firmware "edid/edid1.bin" failed (err=-2)
```

I have put the edid1.bin in `/usr/lib/firmware/edid/` and `/lib/firmware/edid/`, but I still get this error.

I have renamed the file to `edid.bin`:

```
$ ls -la /usr/lib/firmware/edid/edid.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 256  1月 27 13:15 /usr/lib/firmware/edid/edid.bin

$ ls -la /lib/firmware/edid/edid.bin 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 256  1月 27 13:18 /lib/firmware/edid/edid.bin

$ cat /etc/default/grub |grep firmware
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="drm.edid_firmware=/lib/firmware/edid/edid.bin quiet splash"
```

Comment: please edit & paste the output of `ls -la /usr/lib/firmware/edid/edid1.bin`

Comment: AMDGPU forces me to do this just because that they don't have the ability to output full range RGB.

Comment: Why could I do it on Manjaro and Ubuntu 18.10, instead of Ubuntu 18.04.1?

Comment: does the error message still mention edid1.bin ?

Comment: @cmak.fr No, but it mentioned edid.bin

Comment: I have a similar problem and it seemed to work in Ubuntu 18.10 but not in Ubuntu 18.04 but does was not the case. Well, not my case.
After installing cryptsetup in Ubuntu 18.10 it ceased to work.
I reported the bug in launchpad, please comment there too.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1814938